# Cual es el error en la Query?

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 tablas una con clave principal ID_TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL y la otra con ID_TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL. La segunda tiene una relacion de uno a mucho con la primera y tiene dentro de ella la clave principal de la primera. la query es que dando el id de la segunda me de los datos de la primera.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM SII.TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL F
 LEFT JOIN TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL CI 
    ON F.ID_TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL = CI.ID_TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL
    WHERE CI.ID_TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL = 5;
```

Comment: ¿Qué tabla representa `ID` (en la 4ª línea)? No la has puesto en el `FROM`, ¿no tienes que ponerla ahí?

Comment: Era un ci pero sigue sin ir

Comment: ¿Podrías dar algunos ejemplos con datos (reales o inventados) de las tablas? Y también un ejemplo de lo que esperas que ocurra, y lo que está ocurriendo con tu código actual. Me es difícil imaginármelo sin más detalles.

Comment: si yo te doy el id  CI.ID_TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL = 5 me das todo los campos de  esta tabla TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL cuyo id corresponda con el de la 2ª tabla .

Answer (score 0):

No sé si esta query es equivalente a la que quieres, pero yo lo haría así, sin `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT IF.*
FROM TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL IF, TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL TIF
WHERE IF.ID_TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL = TIF.ID_TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL
AND TIF.ID_TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL = 5
```

Comment: SQL Error [42704]: "UHFSII.TIPO_CLAVE_IDENTIFICACION_FISCAL" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.26.14
ese error me da